# What are some leguminous food trees suited for a Mediterranean climate?

Tags: food, trees

I can think of [carob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carob), which already grows in the area.

What other kinds would be a good source of nutrition and thrive in a Mediterranean climate with little annual rainfall?

Other tree suggestions welcome, [leguminous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legume) or not!

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any leguminous trees which produce edible fruit. Olives are the obvious trees for a dry Mediterranean climate. Then the citrines and Almonds Wallnuts and sweet chestnuts. But if you are emphasizing dryness what about coming down to ground level with pineapples?